# AVSpeechSynthesizer doesn't read short words

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm using AVSpeechSynthesizer to generate speech in my app,
Problem is - When it has to read the word "IT" (for example), as a standalone word and not as part of the sentence - it reads the characters, instead of the word. Is there a way to workaround ? Or force it to read it as a word ?

Comment: AVSpeechSynthesizer tends to treat the combination of capital letters as an abbreviation. Have you tried with "it" (all lower case). As far as I tested, AVSpeechSynthesizer read "it" as "it" is.

Comment: You are right. silly me :) Thanks!